# Better approach to create mongodb schema array of objects in same collection or create new collection save a reference

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm curious to know which is better approach to  design a Schema

1) let's say collection xyz

```
{
field1:anything
field2: anything
pqr:[{ name:String , value:Number} ]
}
```

2)

```
 xyz collection        and pqr collection
     {                                 {
                                           reference id of xyz,
                                           name:String , 
                                          value:Numbee
    field1:anything                    }
    field2: anything

    }
```

## Note: consider that in first approach array won't exceed the size more than 250

Answer (score 0):

I think that the first approach is better than second because the objects in array field are not complex. 
But I think you should see the request that you will respond. For example, if you have the request `GET /xyz` and you don't need to return the pqr array, the first approach is the chosen one.
However if you have the request `GET /xyz/:id/pqr` or you need to return the pqr array in `GET /xyz` the second approach is better, because you maybe want to paginate this request and at second approach is easy to implement because is a `db.collection.find(query).skip(page * size).limit(size)`, but in first approach you have to resolve this in memory or with an aggregation.

PD: sorry for my english.

Comment: thanks for putting effort in answering this question but my concern is related to efficiency and best practice in designing schema if we know that limit of document won't exceed a threshold value as mentioned above 250 so is it a smart move to create new collection. just for your information if records can be indefinite then second approach is optimal but i was wondering that if array could solve the problem.

Comment: Ok I understand your doubt now thank you. I agree with you as regards your comment on the array size. Mongo's schema-less allows you to denormalize the array field, so if the array has meaning in your model and it is simple to manage, then I recommend the first option. Moreover with this approach you avoid the `$lookup` stage and this will be more efficient. Take care